# Getting errors while using pdfbox to parse pdf files in Java

Tags: java

Please advice me as I am getting errors while using pdfbox to parse pdf files in Java. All the necessary libraries are imported and I am still getting errors.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and the possible solution

See my Java code below / see the errors and stack trace below

```
Error:(32, 10) java: illegal start of type
Error:(32, 13) java: illegal start of type
Error:(32, 14) java: ')' expected
Error:(32, 18) java: ';' expected
Error:(32, 19) java: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(32, 27) java: ';' expected
```

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PdfReader {
    private XMLDecoder cosDoc = null;

    private XMLDecoder pdDoc = null;
  static File file = new File("data/javaPDF.pdf");

    private static PDFParser parser = null;


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PDFTextParser pdf = new PDFTextParser();
        //print out results
        System.out.println(pdf.getParsedText());
        //
    }

    private static class PDFTextParser {


         if(!file.isFile())

        {
            String fileName = null;
            System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
        }
        //Set up instance of PDF parser


        {
            try {
                parser = new PDFParser((RandomAccessRead) new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
    //-------------------------------

    public static String getParsedText() {
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;

        String parsedText = null;
        try {
            parser.parse();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);


        return parsedText;
    }
//            System.err.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document." + e.getMessage());

    {
        if (cosDoc != null) cosDoc.close();
        if (pdDoc != null) pdDoc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors? Please include the exact error and stack trace, and indicate the line that is causing it.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the error and stack trace

Comment: there is "package com.techline.util;" in the middle of a file. Or are these two different files? You mention a stack trace, but there isn't any.

Comment: "private static class PDFTextParser" starts with code, "if(!file.isFile())". Where is the method header / construction header?

Comment: The code was pasted 2ce. I have corrected this. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I just edited your stuff for clarity, I hope I didn't remove your correction?

Comment: no, you did not. Thanks :)

Comment: There were some more edits, but the second thing I pointed to is still there. Either that one is a c & p error, or it is the error you are searching for :-)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by c & p error?

Comment: "copy & paste". Again: the line below "private static class PDFTextParser {" is incorrect.

Comment: The errors are saying that you have code where there should be method declarations and the like. Tilman is pointing out one such location, but there are several. Regular code (`if` statements, etc) have to be inside of methods.

Comment: Hi Guys, Please suggest a solution for me

Comment: We... did. Those line numbers of your error messages indicate where the problems are. The problem is that you're putting code outside of methods.

Comment: The method header is missing. We cannot guess for you what it was. Maybe you had it and accidentally deleted it. Or you copied it from somewhere else and something went wrong. Maybe it was a constructor, then add `PDFTextParser(){` before `if(!file.isFile())`

Comment: ok. ill try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much guys, it's been resolved.

Here's the solution:

```
package com.mypackage.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class ExtractTextSimple
{
    private ExtractTextSimple()
    {
        // example class should not be instantiated
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("data/javaPDF.pdf"));

        System.out.println("No of pages >>"+ document.getNumberOfPages());
        AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
        if (!ap.canExtractContent())
        {
            throw new IOException("You do not have permission to extract text");
        }

        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();


        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

        for (int p = 1; p <= document.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
        {
            // Set the page interval to extract. If you don't, then all pages would be extracted.
            stripper.setStartPage(p);
            stripper.setEndPage(p);

            // let the magic happen
            String text = stripper.getText(document);
            System.out.println("Text >>" + text);
            // do some nice output with a header
            String pageStr = String.format("page %d:", p);
            System.out.println(pageStr);
            for (int i = 0; i < pageStr.length(); ++i)
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(text.trim());
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

}
```